# Why is there an instance of Logstash in the Elastic Cloud deployment?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud

I'm investigating the Elastic Cloud hosted ELK stack (https://www.elastic.co/cloud/elasticsearch-service) and the deployment includes an instance of Logstash.

I thought Logstash was just supposed to be installed on the servers that I'm looking to collect logs from.

What is the intention of the Logstash instance in the hosted deployment?

[image]

Comment: I'm curious to know where you saw an instance of Logstash in ES Cloud.

Comment: In the Kibana management

Comment: Strange! Can you add a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: This is not a Logstash instance, it is the interface for the Centralized Pipeline Management, you can create your pipelines on kibana and deploy on your Logstash instances.