# How to create a pipeline in logstash service in elastic cloud

Tags: logstash, pipeline

I'm evaluating elasticsearch cloud and I tried creating a pipeline which consumes data from a data source and saves it to ES.
I'm not sure how to enable the pipeline once created. There is no option to enable this or debug it.
Please check the attachment
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no Logstash in Elastic cloud, you will need to create logstash instances in your infrastructure or in other cloud service, configure those instances to communicate with your elasticsearch nodes in elastic cloud and then you will be able to deploy the configurations through kibana.

For more information on how to configure those logstash instances, see the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/connecting-to-cloud.html)

Comment: Hi leandro, I have some question. I saw your comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56649949/why-is-there-an-instance-of-logstash-in-the-elastic-cloud-deployment. So does it mean I can send data to logstash instance on elastic cloud? How do my beat communicate to logstash on elastic cloud?